# Cassandra querybuilder selection of multiple column with aggregate function

Tags: java, cassandra, query-builder

[image]
I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE AB (
    aid bigint,
    bid bigint,
    time bigint,
    value int,
    status int,
    PRIMARY KEY (aid, bid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (bid ASC);
```

how to write this query using Querybuilder in cassandra?

```
select count(*),aid from AB where aid = 2;
```

Comment: you have specified the aid, why do you need to select it ??

Comment: My query was for different purpose.(Asynchronous).
OK. tell me syntax of  this query using querybuilder.

select count(*), bid from AB where aid =2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in cassandra with this statement. This kind of doesn't make sense in cassandra since for every bid you would actually get just one back (clustering column and clustering columns are just overwritten should you decide to insert more bid stuff). Also you can't use count in combination with other columns.

You might do this with user defined functions:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html

But then again with this model there is only one concrete instance of B column within the A row.

Edit:
This might not work as you expect it to, you will get the first bid in the partition and the total count of bids:
[image]

Then again if this works for you, even better. I tried combining select columns with count in query builder - doesn't seem combinable. I looked into the driver under the hood basically if there is already a list of columns that you are selecting, you will get an exception.

```
        if (columnNames != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Some columns (%s) have already been selected.", columnNames));
        if (previousSelection != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Some columns ([%s]) have already been selected.", previousSelection));
```

I would advise to go with the prepared statement then.

Comment: Thanks .I have edited the question. Query is already supporting my model. I am just looking for syntax to write the query using querybuilder.  If you can help me with syntax that will be helpful.
TIA.